# Issue displaying subviews above video | Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

The login screen I am designing is near complete but fails to properly display both the username and password textfields once the view controller loads

The following function executes when the view loads - it properly plays the video and displays both the image and loginButton correctly, it appears to also appears to display the textfields for a split second until the video fully loads and plays.

```
func playVideo() {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "videoFile", ofType: "mp4") else {
            return
        }
        
        let asset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        let queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        
        self.playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: queuePlayer, templateItem: playerItem)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: queuePlayer)
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        self.videoLayer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        queuePlayer.play()
        
        videoLayer.bringSubviewToFront(img)
        videoLayer.bringSubviewToFront(usernameTF)
        videoLayer.bringSubviewToFront(passwordTF)
        videoLayer.bringSubviewToFront(signinButton)
        
    }
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: You can make a container view which contain sign in part (img, username,password,btn) and then make it subview to playerview or a container which contain player view.

Comment: Yes, the container view option is a good way of doing this. Just create a container add a playerview and your other components.  

So your view hierarchy looks like below:

container view 
- playerview
- other view (img, usernameTF, passwordTF, signinButton etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can change this code according to your need.

```
var player : AVPlayer?
var playerViewController : AVPlayerViewController?   
func playLiveUrl(url:String){
        let videoURL = URL(string: "http://bla blah.com")
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        self.playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController?.player = self.player
        playerViewController?.view.frame = self.topPlayerView.frame 
        playerViewController?.player?.play()
        self.topPlayerView.addSubview(playerViewController?.view ?? UIView()) // Container topPlayerView which contains a player
        
    }

     var topPlayerView : UIView = {
            let view = UIView()
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.backgroundColor = .black
            return view
        }()
```